# Google Visualization dataview.setRows(): invalid row index error

Tags: javascript

In my code, I created a data view using Google Visualization and it contains over 300 rows. When I try to filter the rows by specifying exact row indexes, the console produces the error:

> SCRIPT5022: Invalid row index 4. Should be in the range [0-380].

Here is the JavaScript:

```
function filter(t) {
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

    if (t.colQuery.value) {
        view.setColumns(t.colQuery.value.split('/'));
    }
    if (t.rowQuery.value) {
        view.setRows(t.rowQuery.value.split('/'));
    }
    chart.draw(view, {
        allowHtml: true
    });
}
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<div id='form'>
    <form id='serverForm'>Enter server name(s):
        <!-- textbox and button for server name(s) -->
        <textarea id='text' onkeypress='checkKey(event, this.form)'></textarea>
        <button onclick='drawChart(this.form); return false;'>Table/Refresh</button>
    </form>
    <form id='queryForm'>Enter column query:
        <!-- textbox and button for queries -->
        <input type='text' id='colQuery'></input>Enter row query:
        <input type='text' id='rowQuery'></input>
        <button onclick='filter(this.form); return false;'>Filter</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you take the input and split by forward slashes, you will get an array of string. However, `setRows()` and `setColumns()` expect arrays of integers (indexes).

You will need to map them into integer first. With little modification, you can do this:

**Change from:**

```
view.setRows(t.rowQuery.value.split('/'));
```

**To this:**

```
view.setRows(t.rowQuery.value.split('/').map(function(v){ return parseInt(v) }));
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It gives me same error except it says NaN instead of 4.

Comment: Can you try the updated code? Anyway, just wondering, do you have a `/` at the end of the input?

Comment: Never mind. I found a solution: replace the function inside map() to Number, so `view.setRows(t.rowQuery.value.split('/').map(Number);` Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad it hints you how to fix it.